# How to use Streams instead of a loop that contains a variable?

Tags: java

I developed this code to check if the string made up of parentheses is balanced. For instance,

Not balanced: `["(", ")", "((", "))", "()(", ")(", ...]`.
Balanced: `["()", "()()", "(())", "(())()", ...]`

I want to use a stream instead of a for-loop. There is a conditional statement inside the loop that checks when the `counter` variable is less than zero. I am unclear know how to include this variable in a stream.

I would welcome feedback on this. Please see my code below:

```
public String findBalance(String input) {
    String[] arr = input.split("");

    Integer counter = 0;

    for (String s : arr) {
        counter += s.equals("(") ? 1 : -1;
        if (counter < 0) break;
    }
    return counter == 0 ? "Balanced" : "Not Balanced";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not implement this using Streams. In the Streams API, you only have access to one element at a time. It should not be used to reference something outside that scope. It is possible, of course, but not recommended

Comment: To be honest, you should do the paranthesis balancing using a stack while iterating over the string using for loop. Streams would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming isn't a good fit. Ask yourself what would happen if you used `parallelStream()`. How would you handle a simple edge case?

```
)(
```

You want to detect when the count dips below 0, even if it later goes back up. It's quite difficult to do that with a parallel stream. The string is best processed sequentially.

Stream operations work best when they are independent and stateless. Stateful actions are better suited for a regular `for` loop like you already have.

Comment: Thank you John for your comments. I am learning Java and you did a really good point thinking about parallelStream. We can say that Stream is not the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see whether Stream could fit.

1. *Sequentially*, by character, maintaining a *nesting stack*, one would need a counter; **reduction** would be feasible.
   However the code is not much better, more verbose and slower. Exploiting parallelism
   would need to handle "...(" & ")...". Possible but not nice.
2. Let's look at a more *parallel* approach: substituting inner *reducible expressions* (redex `()`) recursively/repeatedly:

   ```
   public String findBalance(String input) {
       String s = input.replaceAll("[^()]", "");
       for (;;) {
           String t = s.replace("()", "");
           if (t.length() == s.length()) {
               break;
           }
           s = t;
       }
       return s.isEmpty();
   }
   ```

Though a split-and-conquer parallelism is feasible here, the problem is the repetition needed for things like `(())`.

For a Stream one might think of a `flatMap` or such. However Stream processing steps do **not repeat** (in the current java version), hence not easily feasible.

So a Stream solution is not fitting.

One could combine the recursion function with a Stream splitting the passed string,
to use a parallel Stream, but even with 16 cores and strings of length 1000 that will not be considerably faster.

Comment: Hey Joop! You did a really good job explaining your solutions. And you had an interesting way to solve this problem. Thank you so much.